# Don't know why my OS X kext with a lower probe score is being matched

Tags: macos, bluetooth, iokit, kernel-extension

I am trying to selectively screen and disable certain USB devices.  For that purpose I have written an `IOUSBInterface` driver that specifies wildcards for `idProduct`, `idVendor`, and `bcdDevice`.  Anytime I do *not* want to disable a given device, I set `probeScore` to 0 and return.

The `probeScore` approach works in almost all cases, and I can see my driver considering each USB device in turn in `system.log`.  But in the case of the Bluetooth USB Host Controller, the kernel attaches my driver to it despite my probe score of 0.  By comparison, if my driver is not present, the Bluetooth USB Host Controller matches with a probe score of 90,000.

It is true that my driver specifies `OSBundleRequired` as `Root`, but the Bluetooth USB Host Controller specifies `OSBundleRequired` as `Safe Boot`, which would seem to put them on the same footing.  On the other hand I'm having the same Yosemite Bluetooth problems as others, and my Bluetooth mouse doesn't respond until after I login, suggesting that the Bluetooth USB Host Controller might not be getting loaded until after boot time.

Comment: I do have FileVault 2 enabled on the machine, which may affect what is visible before unlocking my drive.  When I boot in single user mode and try to explicitly load `/System /Library/Extensions/IOBluetoothFamily.kext/Contents/PlutIns/BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport.kext`, I get an invalid signature error even though the system has no problem loading that driver once I log in.  Perhaps I need to ask this question on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The `kextcache` command line tool has a `-print-diagnostics` flag which might help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: @pmdj I'm having a bit of trouble with kextcache.  I tried `sudo kextcache -system-caches -print-diagnostics -v 6` and some other options, but didn't really find what I was looking for.  What usage did you have in mind?

Comment: It would have shown any reason why loading your kext might not work. Evidently there is none. See my answer for what I suspect might be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Completely rewritten answer as I'd misunderstood the question**

First off, [from the horse's mouth](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1076/_index.html):

*"Note that you should never add your own IOProbeScore property to a USB driver's property list."*

That's probably why you're not having much joy with the probe score. (Note that the above recommendation only applies to USB devices; disregard for Thunderbolt etc.)

If modifying your personality matching dictionary to not match the device in question isn't practical (it sounds like you want to decide at runtime, so that's a good reason) then override your driver's `probe()` method and selectively return `this` or `NULL` from it depending on whether you want your (blocker) driver to claim the device or not. Returning `NULL` from `probe()` should always work - if it's causing trouble, you most likely have a bug in your code somewhere.

Comment: Do we perhaps have a miscommunication here?  I am using 10.10 and kext-dev-mode, and my problem is not that my kext _won't load_, but rather that it captures the hardware normally driven by the Bluetooth USB Host Controller, even when I return a negative match score.  I had tried returning NULL earlier, but got some panics along the way, so I thought perhaps it was more graceful to return an impossibly low score.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok, you're right, I misunderstood your question. If you want Apple's driver to take over, then if narrowing your match criteria isn't practical, returning `NULL` from your overridden `probe()` is indeed the best way to not match. If that's causing a panic, then you have a bug in your code; it's not inherent to rejecting the probe. IOProbeScore is notoriously unreliable for USB devices, so I'm not hugely surprised you're not having much joy from that.

Comment: Right, I've updated my answer to something that's hopefully useful. If you're still having crashes after returning `NULL`, feel free to open another question, and I'll do my best to diagnose. :-) Sorry about the wild goose chase.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense.  I will feel free to liberally return NULL anytime I don't want to take over a device, and I'll ignore the unsightly "*::probe fails" entries in system.log.  And I have no IOProbeScore in my plist, so we're good on that count.